# Why does a subclass of AbstractMvcEndpoint return a 404 despite the method being called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Putting a breakpoint inside my endpoint method, i see it is called and it returns without any error. But when it reaches the browser, it says it was a 404 error.

```
@Configuration
@ManagementContextConfiguration
@CacheController
public class TestController extends AbstractMvcEndpoint
{
    public TestController()
    {
        super( "/testendpoint", false, true );
    }

    @GetMapping( value = "/testendpoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )
    public String getSomething(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: `return "hello";` is incorrect. It should be a JSON object.

Comment: @DoNhuVy After fixing that, I still get a 404 (I returned `"{}"`)

Comment: Because the result is RESTful, therefore, it return to `{}` is correct. It should be tested by `curl` command more than use Web page interface. I see a good example at here: https://moelholm.com/2016/08/18/spring-boot-introduce-your-own-insight-endpoints/

Comment: @DoNhuVy Can you please put that as an answer (including the link to the article) this fixed it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `getSomething(...)` has `return "hello";`  Therefore, it will return a normal view (**Web page view**).

Because you want return JSON object, the outcome of the below method

```
@GetMapping( value = "/testendpoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )
public String getSomething(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
    return "hello";
}
```

should be a **JSON object**.

For testing REST end-point, it should be use command `curl` (on Linux). If you use web browser, you can use JSON mark-up plug-in (For example: [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en)).

You can do something likes [this](https://moelholm.com/2016/08/18/spring-boot-introduce-your-own-insight-endpoints/) with sample [source code](https://github.com/moelholm/smallexamples/tree/master/springboot-actuator-custominsight).